# Ionic 3 FileTransfer throws errorcode 1 for download

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm trying to implement a download function in Ionic 3 using File Transfer plugin file as per the explanation here, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/. And here's the code,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
  providers: [FileTransfer, FileTransferObject],
})
export class DetailsPage {
  storageDirectory: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform, private transfer: FileTransfer, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetailsPage');
  }

  downloadImage(imageURL) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        imageURL = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/fl_attachment/v1514410469/l98gddyf9uoj7k9bljqi.jpg';
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();        
        const imageName = imageURL.split('/').pop();

        fileTransfer.download(imageURL, this.storageDirectory + imageName).then((entry) => {
            const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: `Download Succeeded!`,
                subTitle: `${imageURL} was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alertSuccess.present();
        }, (error) => {
            const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: `Download Failed!`,
                subTitle: `${imageURL} was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alertFailure.present();
        });
    });
  }
}
```

It is throwing error code 1. As per documentation, it is `FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR: 1`. But as you can see, there's a file present in the   specified [URL](https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/fl_attachment/v1514410469/l98gddyf9uoj7k9bljqi.jpg).

I tried with different URL, URL with `encodeURI()`, but noting works. Any help on this would be greatly helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whomever getting this error, I suggest to print the error in console and view it through chrome debugger. In my case it printed,

```
{
    body: null
    code: 1
    exception: "/l98gddyf9uoj7k9bljqi.jpg (Read-only file system)"
    http_status: 200
    source: "https://res.cloudinary.com/beinspired/image/upload/v1514410469/l98gddyf9uoj7k9bljqi.jpg"
    target: "l98gddyf9uoj7k9bljqi.jpg"
}
```

So, it is due to the reason that, I missed to initialise `storageDirectory`, so it was trying to store it in the root folder of the filesystem which was only having read only access. So, after adding,

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    return false;
  }

  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalDataDirectory;
  }
  else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
    this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalDataDirectory;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

to the constructor, it’s all fine.